# How to get fixed numbers on axis of line graph with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I've seen this question before on Stack Overflow, but for whatever reason the answers haven't worked for me. Can you please help me make a line graph that uses non-scientific-notation numbers?

Here's my code:

```
\pgfplotsset{timeAcc/.style={
    xmin=1, 
    xmax=100, 
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=100,
    scaled ticks=false,
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    xlabel={Window Size (ms)},
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    grid=major,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis} [
        timeAcc,
        title=Example Model,
        legend entries={Total accuracy, GMR, Usage},
    ]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [y=d, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So I'm using `scaled ticks=false` and `format/fixed`, but my output looks like this:

[image: A picture of my graph]

Why is pgfplots ignoring the tick commands, and how can I change that?

Comment: search for `log ticks with fixed point` in the manual

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But now the y-axis starts around 40 instead of 0 - is there a quick fix for that?

Comment: Never mind - I found `semilogxaxis` worked for my goal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @Miryafa Can you please add an answer with a MWE of the solution and ideally some words how it works?

Comment: @Schweinebacke It seems I can't because the question has been put on hold. 

That said, I don't understand the reason given.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question, because I think closing a question because it is answered in a comment is nonsense. Comments are not answers and shouldn't be. And even if they answer a questions this should not be a reason to close a question. Closing a question because of an answering comment prioritize comments above answers. Because answering a question by an answer also is not a reason to close a question. For this question having an answer that explains why and how `semilogaxis` should be used would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}` doesn't work when using `loglogaxis`. Instead you have to use `log ticks with fixed point` (credit to percusse).

In addition, if you only want one axis to have log format you can setup your graph as a `semilogaxis`, which makes one axis log-scale and the other linear-scale. In this case, that would be `semilogxaxis`, and would look like this:

```
\pgfplotsset{timeAcc/.style={
    xmin=1, 
    xmax=100, 
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=100,
    scaled ticks=false,
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
    log ticks with fixed point,
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    xlabel={Window Size (ms)},
    ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    grid=major,
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis} [
        timeAcc,
        title=Example Model,
        legend entries={Total accuracy, GMR, Usage},
    ]
    \addplot table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [y=c, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \addplot table [y=d, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```